# Node.js and Express relationship

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules

I'm trying to understand the connection between Node.js and Express.

My Code for creating a Node.js Server:

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./https1/key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./https1/cert.pem')
};

const server  = https.createServer(options, function(req,res){
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end(`Hello world!!!!!!!!!!! \n`);
});

server.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('Server listening on port 3000 \n');
});
```

I run a curl operation `curl -k localhost:3000` and it gives me a "Hello World" Output

My code for creating an Express Server:

```
// call the packages we need
var express    = require('express');       
var app        = express();                 
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// ROUTES FOR OUR API
var router = express.Router();
// test route to make sure everything is working (accessed at GET    http://localhost:8080/api)
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'hooray! welcome to our api!' });   
});
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

Is it possible for us to mix both of these?

To be more specific, I would like to create my Server using the Node.js way, but create my routes using the Express way. Can I do it or should I just follow one methodology? What is the connection between Node.js and Express? I understand that Express is just a  framework for Node.js but where exactly does the deviation occurs if at all any?

Can I mix and combine the two when required?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You surely can that's the way to create a Secure HTTPS server with express and followed in most projects

```js
const https = require('https');
const express    = require('express');
const app = express();

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./https1/key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./https1/cert.pem')
};
const server = https.createServer(options, app);


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.send('hello world')
}
server.listen(config.port, () => {
  console.log(`Express server listening on port ${port} in ${app.get('env')} mode`);
});
```

Now add your routes and all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can combine `nodejs` and `express`, but not encourage you to combine those unless you have specific purpose such as using `AWS lambda` or making specific OS tasks that has to be made only with pure node.

As you already know, `express` is just a framework. You can write code more shortly using `express`.

For example, to make the browser displaying Hello world,

```
// nodejs version

const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World!\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});



// express version

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const port = 3000;

app.listen(port, (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!\n');
})
```

More easier, and intuitive.

Comment: And how do you suggest to create a https server with express?